# Copying value to a cell in a different sheet. Cell is found using vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm new to VBA and have been trying a lot to solve my problem. Since I almost never use VBA I depend completely on pre-made code I find on the web and/or this website. I can't find the code for the problem I am facing now.

I want to implement a button in my Excel worksheet which renews a value by clicken the button, therefore I need VBA.

I have two sheets. In sheet 1 is a value in cell D24 I want to copy to a cell in sheet 2. The cell in sheet 2 is found by using vlookup with a value in sheet 1 (value in D4).

The formula I would use:
=VLOOKUP(D4;'Sheet1'!A:C;3;0).

With this formula I find the value/specific cell I need to change. How can I replace the value I found by using VLOOKUP with the value I have in cell D24 (sheet 1)?

I hope the explanation of my problem is a bit clear and I hope any of you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Mark

Comment: Have a look at `MATCH`. It will return the cell with the value in D4

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't quite understand. Can you expand on your answer?